Is it fair to play the game for $1000

"In a game where a fair coin is tossed 100 times, the player wins
\$60,000 if more than 60 heads appear. The cost to play the game is
\$1,000. Is it fair to play the game based on the expected value?"

My approach to get to the answer is to find the expected value of the game by calculating the chances of winning the game. As per my understanding, we should use Binomial distribution formula and thus the chances of winning the game are given by:
$P(X = 61) = \binom{100}{61} 0.5^{100}$
I have not considered other cases where the number of heads is more than 61 because once we have 61 heads, the player has already won.
Then as per the formula of expected value
$E(Game) = 60000*\binom{100}{61} 0.5^{100}$
Is my approach correct? Is there any other approach to solve the problem?
The above question was asked to me in an interview. I gave my approach to the problem, but the interviewer seemed not satisfied with the solution.

No, your approach is incorrect. You are computing Pr for exactly 61 heads, which will be a very small value. You need to compute for $P(X\geq 61)$

The game is fair if the probability to win is exactly $\frac{1}{60}$ , it is not asked whether it is underfair or overfair. So you just have to compute the probability to win and to check whether it is exactly $\frac{1}{60}$

As this is an interview question, I would expect that a quick approximate solution is desired.
The total number of heads follows a Binomial distribution with $p = 1/2$ and $n=100$.  The standard deviation of a Binomial distribution is $ \sigma = \sqrt{n p (1-p)}$, so $\sigma = 5$. If $60$ heads appear, this outcome is $2$ standard deviations above the mean.
The distribution is also approximately Normal.  A fact often used in statistics is that the probability of a value from a Normal distribution being $2$ or more standard deviations from the mean is about $0.05$. But that figure is for a result either above or below the mean.  Since we are interested only in a result $2$ or more standard deviations above the mean, the probability is $0.025$.  So the expected value of the pay-off is about $0.025 \times 60,000 = 1,500$ dollars.  Since this is greater than the cost to play the game, it is advantageous to the player.

A moderate shortcut analysis is feasible.
Extending the comment of true blue anil, by symmetrical considerations, the probability of getting at least $~51~$ heads is
$$ A = \frac{1 - \left[ ~\binom{100}{50} \times 2^{-100} ~\right]}{2}.$$
Further, the probability that the number of heads is between $~51~$ and $~60~$ inclusive is
$$B = 2^{-100} \times \sum_{k=51}^{60} \binom{100}{k}.$$
Therefore, the probability of getting at least $~61~$ heads is
$$A - B.$$
I am assuming that winning $~\$60000~$ does not also get the initial investment of $~\$1000~$ returned. This implies that if $~A - B = \dfrac{1}{59},~$ then the game is a break even proposition.
Then, if $~A - B > \dfrac{1}{59},~$ it is a winning proposition.
My knowledge of statistics is virtually non-existent.  I suspect that even the algebra in this answer can be short-circuited by considering how many standard deviations away from $~50~$ is the number $~60.$

Since this is a binomial experient the exact expected value is simply
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=60}^{100}\mathbb{P}(H=k)\cdot 60'000=60'000\sum_{k=60}^{100}{100\choose k}\cdot2^{-100}\approx 60'000\cdot 2.844\%=1706.4$$
whose approximate value I have computed easily using WA.
Another approach is using the Central Limit Theorem and approximating the binomial distribution using the normal
$$X=\mathcal{B}\left(100,\frac12\right)\approx \mathcal{N}\left(50,5\right)=Y$$
so that the probability of getting more than $60$ coins becomes
$$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 60)\approx \mathbb{P}(Y\geq 60)=1-\mathbb{P}(Y\leq 60)=1-\mathbb{P}(5X+50\leq 60)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2)=2.275\%$$
and multiplying this by 60'000 gets you indeed close to the exact value.
And since the expected value is way more than \$1000, it's more than fair to play the game.

In your first equation, you have to sum from $61$, not $60$. And in your second equation using the normal approximation, you have to use $60.5$ (the continuity correction factor).
